# Change The Azure App Service To Display A Different Timezone From a Users Settings Stored Value?

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, timezone, blazor

I am aware of changing an Azure Web App timezone in the configuration using 'WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE' and the 'Time Zone You Want'.

It works great.

However, in my user setting page/table I'd like to store a value of the users selected and database stored/selected timezone.  Is this possible to send that value when loading the site to change it out per users login?

In my mind it changes the value of 'WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE' and 'THIS VALUE' based on the users login and what their stored and returned value is from the table stored in the database.  So I'd have it load that on site load from the user and them being logged in and pass it to... somewhere..

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting per user. It is for the entire application. This I believe you would need to handle in your application code itself.

Comment: Send it as a user claim. Your services then just need to query the claim and convert `DateTimeOffset` or `DateTime`. I recommend using `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Brian Parker - Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` if you are wanting to change the time zone per-user.  Instead, you should avoid relying on the concept of the "local time zone" in your application code.  That means, don't call `TimeZoneInfo.Local`, `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.Today`, or `DateTimeOffset.Now`, `DateTimeKind.Local`, `.ToLocalTime()`, etc.

Instead, work with time in a specific time zone by using the `TimeZoneInfo` object.

For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userTimeZoneId);
DateTimeOffset now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tz);
```

The above is the best practice anyway.

`WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` is a *hack* for when you can't change old code that relies on the local time zone.  It works under the hood by intercepting system calls and lying to .NET about what the local time zone actually is.  It cannot be changed per user.  Even if you found a way to do that, I wouldn't recommend it as it likely wouldn't be thread-safe.  In other words, you may find that one user gets their time in another user's time zone when your site is busy.

Just handle the time changes in your *own* code and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, very clear to understand.